# Solve equation set using MATLAB syms

Tags: matlab, equation

[The question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu4ly.jpg)

I have write the MATLAB code, like this

```
syms x x1 x2 x3 y y1 y2 y3 t0 t1 t2 t3 v

[x,y]=solve((x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2-(v*(t1-t0))^2==0,(x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2-(v*(t2-t0))^2==0,(x-x3)^2+(y-y3)^2-(v*(t3-t0))^2==0)
```

but the ans is empty, like this

```
x =
 
Empty sym: 0-by-1
 
 
y =
 
Empty sym: 0-by-1
```

In fact, the equation set does have a solution, so I want to know how to correct the code?

Comment: Check the doc, the correct usage of solve is `solve(equation,variable)` and not `solve(equation, equation, equation)` you can group multiple equations together by using brackets. Also there is a trivial solution to your problem when `x = x1,x2,x3`, `y = y1,y2,y3` and `v=0`.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#buezrr6-4) say

> If solve returns an empty object, then no solutions exist.

Cleaning up your problem a bit,

```
Eq1 = (x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2-(v*(t1-t0))^2==0;
Eq2 = (x-x2)^2+(y-y2)^2-(v*(t2-t0))^2==0;
Eq3 = (x-x3)^2+(y-y3)^2-(v*(t3-t0))^2==0;
EqSys = [Eq1,Eq2,Eq3]; % create a system of equations
solve(EqSys,x) % <= specify, for which variable the system of equations should be solved
```

made me feel that you want to solve vectors rather than distinct variables, right? Are the entries independent? Or is the solution `x` indeed a scalar value?
If not, solving a single equation

```
solve(Eq1,x)
```

does return an answer

```
ans =
 
 x1 + (y - y1 + t0*v - t1*v)^(1/2)*(y1 - y + t0*v - t1*v)^(1/2)
 x1 - (y - y1 + t0*v - t1*v)^(1/2)*(y1 - y + t0*v - t1*v)^(1/2)
```